# How can I center an oversized fullscreen video in firefox vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css

i want to center an ovesized fullscreen video.
it works in webkit, but not in firefox.

demo: http://pascha.org/test/

the video-logo should always stay in the vertical/horizontal center, if you have wide browser resolutions > 1300px, like it does in chrome. in firefox though its only centered horizontally.
(for small resolutions it does not matter, i load a different video there.)

anyone knows the magic lines?

code for history purposes (same as in the demo):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#slider {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.id3 {
    background-color: #253061;
    z-index: 1;
}
.plane {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
}

.videoslide {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.bgvid {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider">
  <div class="plane id3" rel="3">
    <div class="videoslide">
      <video autoplay="autoplay" loop class="bgvid">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="startseite_5_1251.mp4"></source>
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="innerplane">
      <div class="text" rel=4>
        <div class="title">Wir produzieren aufregenden Video Content -</div>
        <div class="title subtitle3 bmarg50">Zum Beispiel f&uuml;r den Ryder Cup.</div>
        <a class="sliderlink link3" href="#">Projekt ansehen</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.bgvid {
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Note: to make the .innerplane clickable you need to position it to something different from "static". position: relative; for example.

Comment: thanks, thats really cool! i was trying with translateY too, but was this one step shy.